# WSL Ubuntu 18.04 shows wrong Cpu_allowed mask

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cpulimit

Ubuntu 18.04 running under WSL detects my CPU wrong:

```
$ cat /proc/self/status | grep Cpus_allowed
Cpus_allowed:   00000001
```

The CPU is an i7-4510U (2 cores/4 threads) so I expected:

```
Cpus_allowed:   f
```

or similar (ff, ffffffff, 0000000f).

The peculiar thing is that when I run 4 processes, each process gets a CPU thread, and thus runs at 400% CPU utilization. So it is as if the CPU mask is not respected.

Also `taskset` is not respected. This should use a single thread (100%), but it uses all 4 (400%):

```
taskset 2 parallel -j4 'bzip2 < /dev/zero >' ::: {1..10}
```

Is this a bug - possibly in WSL? And if so: Where do I report it?

**Background**

The problem described on https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1442563 is explained by the above: GNU Parallel detects the wrong number of CPU threads because it looks at the CPU mask in `/proc/*/status` to determine how many CPU threads it is allowed to use.

Comment: WSL is not the Linux kernel, it's a Microsoft compatibility layer that interfaces with the Windows HAL. Imo there is nothing to report about.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro But why do I see the behaviour that is different from when I use Real Ubuntu? If WSL does not support `taskset` or the cpu mask, why lie about it? Could they not just have left it out of `/proc/*/status`.

Comment: If any Linux program need some kernel specific stuff WSL failed there, like things with /proc, /var, /run. You can report issue https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/. Please search there if you find similar issue.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Looks good. Thanks.